# Shrinking size of VMDK file for VMWare machine that only has ~10GB used

Tags: partitioning, vmware-workstation

I have a VM that I share/synchronize daily over a NAS, so size is of high importance.

The image is stored as a single VMDK file, which is ~31GB in size. However, so far as I can tell, it *doesn't need to be that large.*

The VMWare Player settings suggest that ~21.5GB is unused, and the output of `df` suggests that around ~13GB is used (assuming this includes swap) when it's actually running.

**I have tried** both defragmenting the disk, as well as compacting the disk, in the VMWare settings - both operations complete almost immediately.

**How can I shrink this VM down to a more manageable size?** When it was split across multiple files (there were ~30 of them) prior to my converting it to a single file, it still took up roughly the same amount of space.

**I've tried** using the vmware-vdiskmanager.exe program, and it took ~5 minutes to both defrag (-d) and then shrink (-k) the image, but it went from 32.4GB to 32.1GB. Not a huge difference.

Note that the size of the VMDK file (in Windows Explorer) was measured after the machine had been powered down.

[image: Virtual Machine Settings]

[image: Console Output in VM]

[image: VMDK Image in Windows Explorer]

Comment: I presume you have tried compact the VM that will remove any overhead within the vhdd file itself?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, as mentioned, neither the "Compact" nor "Defragment" buttons in the VM settings pictured seem to have any effect. Also per the dupe, my VMDK is already configured to be a "grow as you go" disk, with a maximum size of 120GB. It's obviously not that large, but still larger than it seems it _needs_ to be.

Comment: Normally whenever I did this to my own VMs I would first shrink the disk within the OS, then compact the disk, then clone the vhdd and replace the original vhdd with the clone.

Comment: @Ramhound Right, the only issue is that within the VM, the disk looks like it's 120GB, so I'm not sure what I would shrink it **to**. I want it to be auto-growing, and I want it to have a max size of 120GB. I just don't want it to take up 30GB on my hard disk if the VM itself is only using ~10GB.

Comment: BTW, that screenshot does not say that 21.5 GB of your .vmdk is unused.  It says that 21.5 GB of your *host disk* is available.

Comment: I am no longer able to add an answer to this question, but using the `vmshrink` program I mentioned in my answer to [How can I shrink my VMware image?](https://superuser.com/questions/323728/how-can-i-shrink-my-vmware-image) might give you better results.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you made the entire 120 GB virtual disk inside the VM a single LVM volume.
Even though you are only using part of it for your actual filesystems.
This can confuse VMWare.

I would recommend to free unused LVM blocks and migrate the used blocks to the front of the disk (inside the Fedora install obviously).
This should create a large part of un-allocated space at the end of the disk (should show as such in GPartEd).

Then do the defrag and shrink again.

If that doesn't help there is 1 more thing you can try:
Convert (a copy of) the VMDK file to either VHD or VDI format and then convert it back to VMDK. This often leads to much smaller file in my experience.

PS.
I would recommend to use VirtualBox to do the conversion. It is more flexible in its conversion options than VMWare.
(Don't install VirtualBox on the same computer as VMWare! They may conflict.)

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to configure my volumes so as to not "confuse" VMWare?

Comment: Do not over-dimension your VMDK that much. Grow it when you need more space (extending is very little effort). That is the only way I know of.